# I am writing a regular expression to get the string between the curly bracket

Tags: apex, visualforce, pattern

I am trying to get all the string from a defined text using pattern class using regex.

```
Pattern MyPattern = Pattern.compile('/[^{\}]+(?=})/g');
```

but it is throwing an error

> Illegal string literal: Invalid string literal '/[^{}]+(?=})/g'.
>   Illegal character sequence }' in string literal.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here `\` is a special character which you need to escape to make it work. So you need something like

```
Pattern MyPattern = Pattern.compile('/[^{\\}]+(?=})/g');
```

Check I have used extra `\` to escape the sign.

Also, the JavaScript notation (`//g`) won't work the way you expect in Apex Code, because it uses the Java syntax. Instead, to turn on the "g" flag, you'd use `(?g)`:

```
Pattern MyPattern = Pattern.compile('(?g)[^{\\}]+(?=})');
```

You can read more about how patterns work in the [Java documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).